# Where do I put my stubs?

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, stub

I've been utilizing stub implementations of my `abstract` classes for testing purposes. Currently, my unit tests are residing in a `test` directory alongside my `src` directory.

I'm wondering if there is a best-practice for where to place any stubs that are used in the testing. I have been trying several things, but part of me seems to be perpetually perturbed no matter what I do.

Things I have tried:

- Declaring the stub implementations within the actual unit tests using them. This falls flat when you have to use the stub in multiple JUnit classes.
- Placing the stubs into the same package as their parent class. This seems like a terrible idea since it suddenly features test code polluting the packages in `src`.
- Keeping the stub classes somewhere in the `test` package structure. This seems like the most reasonable option, but I am not sure what the best way to do this is.

Bear in mind, I am probably over-thinking this. Is there any information on best-practices that could put my mind to rest? Is switching to a mock framework a solution to this dilemma?

Much appreciated.

Comment: Stubs go with the tests whether in the same folder or in some other folder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 3rd option is definitely better than the other two for the reasons you've given.  I like to refer to [the Maven directory structure during times like this](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html), and it doesn't seem to imply anything different than your 3rd option.

What I do is create the stub as an inner class inside the test itself.  Once this gets too messy or needs to be reused, I put the stubs in the same package as the abstract class, but under the `test` directory.

---

It might be worth knowing that a lot of projects evolve to have "Builder" objects that work like this:

```
Person person = new PersonBuilder().withName("John Doe").withDefaultAddress().build();
```

The reason you do this is because sometimes a `Person` needs to be created lots of different ways depending on what you're testing.  Having just one `PersonStub` may not be enough.